# I am having this error issue when I try to reset the password using laravel jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, reset

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)" this is the error message that is displayed

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you updated env file with your credentials

Answer (score 0):

It’s related to your environment file .env and the email setup. Its going to need to be debugged as to what the email setting should be and then if they emails are even getting out from your server/localhost.